# Using Google Analytics and Piwik for the same website

Tags: google-analytics

Is it okay to use both Google Analytics and Piwik at the same time for one website? I love both of them and like certain features from both.

Comment: Yes you can use multiple analytic programs. We use Analytics and Hit Analysis (I am the dev at Hit Analysis) with no problem. In fact, many analytical experts will say you should always use more than 1 program

Comment: thank you.. Actually I am new to web development so still in initial learning phase. Kindly put your comment as an Answer so that I can vote it up.

Comment: I'm sorry to say @Saad that your question is off topic and will be closed. There is a http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ for this type of question though, and stackexchange for dev questions.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't know that. I once asked a question domain on stackoverflow and someone from there recommended me to ask such questions on superuser and closed the topic there too.. Thank you I will take care next time.

Comment: no worries. Each website on the StackExchange sites has a help center. In there it will explain what is considered on / off topic :)

Comment: Yes. I use both of them on my personal website.

Comment: I decided to go with Clicky and Google Analytics because Piwik free version needs to be resided on our server which I read causes a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use multiple analytic programs. We use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) and [Hit Analysis](https://www.hitanalysis.net) with no problem (I am the dev at Hit Analysis).

The problem is tracking visitors is not easy - and therefore results are never accurate. People have internet security, different browser, different browser settings, javascript on or off, cookies enabled or disabled the list goes on and on.

This is why many analytical experts will say you should always use more than 1 program. This will hopefully give you a more balanced view.